# how semantic web could be useful in a CMS Forum

Tags: content-management-system, forum, semantic-web, jena, dbpedia

I am doing a project to integrate Semantic web technologies in Content Management System.

I already know the semantic theory and i know how to write the semantic web code, i also know how to use semantic web tools like `JENA.NET`, `DOTNETRDF` .. etc. and i have enough information about `dbpedia`, `Freebase` and other semantic websites.

My question is : how to use all of that in a practical online world like CMS Forum?, how semantic web could be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a forum, you could take advantage of [SIOC](http://sioc-project.org/) or [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/) ontologies.

A few advantages that you could get by using semantic web for a forum would be:

- interoperability with other semantic ready services / programs
- the power of SPARQL requests
- all your data in a big semantic graph
- better organic SEO with RDFa

Answer (score 0):

I only see one useful way: The pages of your CMS need to “contain, in addition to standard text information, some machine-readable or at least machine-intuitable semantic data.” (see [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_wiki#Example)) So you will, first of all, have to provide input mechanisms for editors to enter the semantic data. Like other databases, the data isn’t useful unless you implement some usage of the data.

Let’s say you have a books review website, you might want to enter the books’ ISBNs as semantic data, and then you could use this in the view to link to the books’ metadata in library catalogues, provide methods to run a geolocation search of the nearest library holding the book, or link to online available full text, etc. You still will have to find these services in the world and implement their APIs.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, So for a Forum ,do you expect any benefit or feature that could be achieved though the Semantic web rather than the current standard technology.